# Can't perform actions with objects

Tags: java, oop

I am an engineering student, busy with a project using DrJava as an IDE (it is the standard IDE we use during the course), and the Princeton STDLIB.

I have been having problems with understanding, writing and using objects.  I would like to ask what is wrong with the way I wrote my following code.  I will give the error lines after the coding:

```
public class GameObject 
{
 // Default implementation of a game object

 private  double  G = 6.67408e-11;
 private  double  radiusKoeff = 0.01;

 public class Planet
 {
   double mass;
   double size;
   double velocityX;
   double velocityY;
   double positionX;
   double positionY;

   public Planet(double m, double vx, double vy, double px, double py)
   {
     mass = m;
     size = m * radiusKoeff;
     velocityX = vx;
     velocityY = vy;
     positionX = px;
     positionY = py;
   }//constructor for the planet type

   public double GravForce(Planet a, Planet b)
   {
     double distanceX, distanceY, distance;
     distanceX = Math.abs(a.positionX - b.positionX);
     distanceY = Math.abs(a.positionY - b.positionY);
     distance = Math.sqrt((distanceX)*(distanceX) + (distanceY)*(distanceY));

     double force = (G * a.mass * b.mass) / (distance*distance);

     return force;
   }//calculates the gravitational force between two objects    
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   String filename = args[0];

   Planet first = new Planet(1.25e24, 1, 0, 0, 0);
   Planet second = new Planet(1e24, 1, 0, 5, 0);

   **StdOut.println(GravForce( first, second ));**
 }
}
```

Error: The method GravForce(GameObject.Planet, GameObject.Planet) is undefined for the type GameObject.

The error is thrown for the GravForce function I try to call.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method like this

```
public double GravForce(Planet b)
   {
     double distanceX, distanceY, distance;
     distanceX = Math.abs(this.positionX - b.positionX);
     distanceY = Math.abs(this.positionY - b.positionY);
     distance = Math.sqrt((distanceX)*(distanceX) + (distanceY)*(distanceY));

     double force = (G * this.mass * b.mass) / (distance*distance);

     return force;
   }//calculates the gravitational force between two objects
```

Then in `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   String filename = args[0];

   Planet first = new Planet(1.25e24, 1, 0, 0, 0);
   Planet second = new Planet(1e24, 1, 0, 5, 0);

   StdOut.println(first.GravForce(second));
 }
```